# How to solve Autofac circular dependency?

Tags: c#, autofac, circular-dependency

Recently started using autofac and I hit a Circular dependency issue, which I had overcome while I was using Unity. Here is my code:

```
 void Main()
 {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // 1) Every class needs logger
    // 2) Logger needs AppSettingsProvider which needs AppEnvironmentProvider
    // 3) Listener needs AppSettingsProvider which needs AppEnvironmentProvider

    builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<AppSettingsProvider>().As<IAppSettingsProvider>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<AppEnvironmentProvider>().As<IAppEnvironmentProvider>().SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<Listener>().As<IListener>().SingleInstance();

    var container = builder.Build();

    var listener = container.Resolve<IListener>();
    listener.Do();

 }

 public interface IListener
 { 
    string Do();
 }

 public class Listener : IListener
 { 
    IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider;
    public Listener(IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider)
    {
        // this class needs IAppSettingsProvider to get some settings
        // but not actually used on this example.
        this.appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProvider;
    }
    public string Do()
    {
        return "doing something";
    }
 }

 public interface ILogger
 { 
    void Log(string message);
 }

 public class Logger : ILogger
 {
    IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider;
    public Logger(IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider)
    {
        this.appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProvider;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        // simplified
        if (this.appSettingsProvider.GetSettings())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
 }

 public interface IAppSettingsProvider
 { 
    // will return a class, here simplified to bool
    bool GetSettings();
 }

 public class AppSettingsProvider : IAppSettingsProvider
 { 
    ILogger logger;
    public AppSettingsProvider(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public bool GetSettings()
    {
        this.logger.Log("Getting app settings");

        return true;
    }
 }


 public interface IAppEnvironmentProvider
 { 
    string GetEnvironment();
 }

 public class AppEnvironmentProvider : IAppEnvironmentProvider
 { 
    ILogger logger;
    public AppEnvironmentProvider(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public string GetEnvironment()
    {
        this.logger.Log("returning current environment");

        return "dev";
    }
 }
```

Any pointers on solving this will be helpful.

Comment: A circular dependency is not something you usually want to work around. It can mean that the architecture should maybe be retaught. But if you really must fix that problem quickly, try property injection rather than constructor injection for one of the injections.

Comment: "which I had overcome while I was using Unity" how did you overcome this with Unity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Use Property Injection
2. Use Factory (that might create a strong dependency with you factory)

Here is an example using Property Injection:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // 1) Every class needs logger
        // 2) Logger needs AppSettingsProvider which needs AppEnvironmentProvider
        // 3) Listener needs AppSettingsProvider which needs AppEnvironmentProvider

        builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<AppSettingsProvider>()
            .As<IAppSettingsProvider>()
            .SingleInstance()
            .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);

        builder.RegisterType<AppEnvironmentProvider>().As<IAppEnvironmentProvider>().SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<Listener>().As<IListener>().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var listener = container.Resolve<IListener>();

        Console.WriteLine(listener.Do());

        Console.Read();

    }

    public interface IListener
    {
        string Do();
    }

    public class Listener : IListener
    {
        IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider;
        public Listener(IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider)
        {
            // this class needs IAppSettingsProvider to get some settings
            // but not actually used on this example.
            this.appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProvider;
        }
        public string Do()
        {
            return "doing something using circular Dependency";
        }
    }

    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(string message);
    }

    public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider;
        public Logger(IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider)
        {
            this.appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProvider;
        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            // simplified
            if (this.appSettingsProvider.GetSettings())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IAppSettingsProvider
    {
        // will return a class, here simplified to bool
        bool GetSettings();
    }

    public class AppSettingsProvider : IAppSettingsProvider
    {
        ILogger logger;
        public AppSettingsProvider()
        {

        }

        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

        public bool GetSettings()
        {
            Logger.Log("Getting app settings");

            return true;
        }
    }


    public interface IAppEnvironmentProvider
    {
        string GetEnvironment();
    }

    public class AppEnvironmentProvider : IAppEnvironmentProvider
    {
        ILogger logger;
        public AppEnvironmentProvider(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        public string GetEnvironment()
        {
            this.logger.Log("returning current environment");

            return "dev";
        }
    }
```

Here is Autofac suggestion:
[Autofac reference](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html?highlight=constructor)

Answer (score 5):

Another work around is to use `Lazy<ILogger>` in the constructor of the dependent services.

```
public class AppSettingsProvider : IAppSettingsProvider
{
    Lazy<ILogger> logger;
    public AppSettingsProvider(Lazy<ILogger> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public bool GetSettings()
    {
        this.logger.Value.Log("Getting app settings");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Autofac provides another option to overcome circular dependencies, In case that A needs B and B needs A, **and B doesn't use A in its constructor**, B can consumes A in a way called **Dynamic Instantiation** see

https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#dynamic-instantiation-func-b

In this way B will use factory method of A, `Func<A>`, in its constructor, (and call it after the constructor, can be in some lazy way) to get get instance of A.

e.g. in the above question change Logger to overcome the circular dependency issue:

```
    public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        Func<IAppSettingsProvider> appSettingsProviderFactory;
        IAppSettingsProvider _appSettingsProvider;
        IAppSettingsProvider appSettingsProvider { get
            {
                if (_appSettingsProvider == null) _appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProviderFactory();
                return _appSettingsProvider;
            }
        }
        public Logger(Func<IAppSettingsProvider> appSettingsProviderFactory)
        {
            this.appSettingsProviderFactory = appSettingsProviderFactory;
        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            // simplified
            if (this.appSettingsProvider.GetSettings())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

(Note: when I added appSettingsProvider.GetSettings(); in Do(), the code in question get into

> Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.

since GetSettings calls Log and Log calls GetSettings but this is another story)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make them mutually exclusive in implementation. Example:

1. You could remove the logging from fetching the settings
2. You could remove the settings check from the logger

Circular references here indicate that you are probably not doing this in the way that is easily maintainable (ie you would have higher coupling).

If you wanted to keep your code as is and hack it to work, you can probably make your log method and getsettings method static. That is a hack in my opinion and you should try either option 1 or 2 listed at the top. The reason for this is because making something static in my opinion should not change the behavior of code but should instead be used for memory optimization (ie see singleton anti pattern for some similar reading in this area).

For your code I would suggest that you remove logging from the appsettingsprovider and to instead use the loggers initation of it to add log statements around the use of that class. Alternately you could explore:

1. the factory pattern to try and wrap creation of either of your classes.
2. Lastly in C# you can have a lambda / function property you could use to pass an instance to a class so that the reference is not going to recursively create new instances.

Comment: - I can't remove logging from any of the classes
- I need settings provider in logger
- I can't make methods static because they all have unit tests.
So I am left with factory or using IocContainer.Resolve<ILogger> in place. What do you think?

Comment: You could split your settings class into two classes, then import the logger settings class and don't import the general settings class which can keep its logging abilities.

Comment: You shouldn't really use the lambda technique. It will work but it loosens your contracts (i.e. it can be tricky to know how a function could be executed when passed as an object). It also bleeds across single responsibility principle. Not following standardized design patterns is what is creating the issues you are facing, so its best not to follow bad practices.

Comment: What I would do is to pass the logger into this method here: public string GetEnvironment()

Comment: You can then put a factory abstraction over that class if you need to for syntactic sugar. You may not need to do that.

Comment: I think passing logger as method param is apt. Thanks!